# How to get a clicked div from a set of other divs

Tags: javascript, html

I was making a box guessing game where there was multiple divs and one of them was the correct one.

The user should click a box to see if it was the correct box or not.

The HTML:-

```
  <body>
    <div class = "wrapper">
      <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
      <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
      <div id="box3" class="box"></div>
      <div id="box4" class="box"></div>
      <div id="box5" class="box"></div>
      <div id="box6" class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I gave all the boxes the (box) class and gave each box its own ID

then I made a variable that stores a random number (randomNum) which is from 0-5 and made a variable for each box and made an array called boxes so tha the correct box is `boxes[randomNum]`

```
const box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
const box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
const box3 = document.getElementById("box3");
const box4 = document.getElementById("box4");
const box5 = document.getElementById("box5");
const box6 = document.getElementById("box6");

let boxes = [box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, box6];

let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
```

now I need to check if the box that is clicked is the correct box or not

I tried making a function that checks if the box that is clicked is equal to the boxes[randomNum] but I had trouble with referencing the clicked box

Does anyone know how I can get the clicked box?

Comment: you don't need id. if you make let arrayBoxs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .box), you have all your box in the arrayBoxs. After you just have to play with the index to address this or this box

Comment: no need to get each element by it's id when you can use `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require you can determine the index of the clicked `.box` within its parent using `parentNode.children`, and comparing this to the random number you generated:

```js
const elementIndexInParent = el => [...el.parentNode.children].indexOf(el);
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .box');
const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * boxes.length + 1);

boxes.forEach(box => {
  box.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const index = elementIndexInParent(e.target) + 1;
    console.log(`${index} is the ${index === randomNum ? 'right answer!' : 'wrong answer.'}`);
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="box1" class="box">1</div>
  <div id="box2" class="box">2</div>
  <div id="box3" class="box">3</div>
  <div id="box4" class="box">4</div>
  <div id="box5" class="box">5</div>
  <div id="box6" class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe to the click event, the `event` object is passed as the first parameter. `event` object has property `target` that contains the element that has been clicked. You can use method `indexOf` of an Array to find your div, as they are equal by reference:

```js
const box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
const box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
const box3 = document.getElementById("box3");
const box4 = document.getElementById("box4");
const box5 = document.getElementById("box5");
const box6 = document.getElementById("box6");

let boxes = [box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, box6];

let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

function onClick(event) {
  if (isCorrectDiv(element.target)) {
    //do stuff
  }
}

function isCorrectDiv(element) {
  return boxes.indexOf(element) === randomNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**querySelectorAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead of getting each element by its id and then use [**addEventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) generate your randomNumber and concatenate the `"box"` string to the number then compare with the selected box `id` to be able to tell which box was clicked.

**Edit:** moved the random number generator inside the eventListener so that it generates a new number, everytime you pick a new box

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

boxes.forEach(x => {
  x.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;//we add +1 because this will generate a random number from 0 to 5
    let chosenBox = "box" + randomNum;
    if (e.target.id == chosenBox) {
      console.log(e.target.id + " is the right box")
    } else {
      console.log(e.target.id + " is not the right box, the right choice was " + chosenBox);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="box1" class="box">box1</div>
  <div id="box2" class="box">box2</div>
  <div id="box3" class="box">box3</div>
  <div id="box4" class="box">box4</div>
  <div id="box5" class="box">box5</div>
  <div id="box6" class="box">box6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need ID attributes. You just need to generate a random integer from 1 to 6, and determine if the box is correct based on the click target.

```js
const randInt = (min, max) => {
  if (max === undefined) { max = min; min = 0; }
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

const
  boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .box'),
  randomNum = randInt(1, boxes.length);

const handleClick = (e) => {
  const
    boxValue = +e.target.textContent.trim(),
    isCorrect = boxValue === randomNum;
  e.target.classList.add(isCorrect ? 'correct' : 'wrong');
  console.log(`${boxValue} is ${isCorrect ? 'correct!' : 'the wrong answer.'}`);
};

const removeHighlight = (e) => {
  e.target.classList.remove('correct', 'wrong');
};

// Add event listeners
boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener('click', handleClick));
boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener('mouseleave', removeHighlight));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 5rem !important; }

*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: thin solid grey;
}

.box:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: yellow;
}

.box.correct:hover {
  background: lime;
}

.box.wrong:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```